# How to wait for response of another method having subscribe call inside

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I have created a FileUploadService in angular which is uploading my file to server. But now the issue is when I am calling the method it is not waiting for response. My code is:

File Upload Service Code:

```
uploadToServer(file: File) {
    const fileModel: FileModel = { fileId: '', name: ''};
    this.fetchToken().subscribe(token => {
        this.postFile(file, token).subscribe(event => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                const uploadPercent = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
            } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
                const key = 'id';
                fileModel.name = file.name;
                fileModel.fileId = event.body[key].toString();                   
                console.log('File uploaded:- ' + file.name);
            }
        });
    });
    return fileModel;
}
fetchToken() {
    return this.httpClient.get('url');
}

  postFile(file: File, token: any) {
    const folderID = '12345';

    const header = new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + (token.access_token)
    });
    const form = new FormData();
    const metadata = {
        name: (file.name), 
        mimeType: (file.type), 
        parents: [folderID], 
    };
    form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {
        type: 'application/json'
    }));
    form.append('file', file);
    return this.httpClient.post('url', form, {
        headers: header,
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events'
    });
}
```

My Component:-

```
onFileChange(event) {
if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const response = this.fileUploadService.uploadToFile(file);
  console.log(response.fileUrl);
  this.formAgent.get('image').setValue(response.Id);
}
}
```

Here the response is not getting any value.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how Observables work =)

Your `uploadToServer` Function should probably return a Observable itself.
A Observable is basically a further abstraction of a Promise. Since you return `fileModel` immediatelly there is no way for the Observabale to emit any Value.

So make the `uploadToServer` Function return a Observable and use [RxJS-Operators](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) to map the response as you wish.

Then you need to call`subscribe` in *MyComponent* to use the mapped Value accordingly.

I encourage you to learn some more about RxJS, how it works and how to use Operators.

I your example, I assume you need to use the Operators [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) because you have a nested Observable (two `.subscribe`) and [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) to map the actual Response to your custom type `{ fileId: '', name: ''}`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what novarx said,
You're falling in the "nested subscriptions" anti-pattern. It would help debugging to convert your subscriptions to a pipeline of operations:

```
return this.fetchToken()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(token => this.postFile(file, token)),
    map(evt => /* convert the event to your custome type */ ),
    catchError(err => {/* don't forget to handle network errors */} ), 
  );
```

You can then subscribe to this in the component.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a help with rxjs switchmap operator.

```
import { interval, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

fromEvent(document, 'click')
  .pipe(
    // restart counter on every click
    switchMap(() => interval(1000))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

For more details look of [rxjs switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)